# Return a List that contain the same Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm working with ASP.net Web Service C#.net3.5 and using the LINQ TO SQL to manipulate with SQL DataBase

and I want to return all the countries information from `Countries`  Table,
so I wrote a web method that return a List of object, each object have two data field `Country_Id`, `Country_Name` and here is the method :

```
public List<CountryObject> ReturnAllCountries()
{
    ProjectTwoDataBaseDataContext DataBase = new ProjectTwoDataBaseDataContext();
    var Country = from a in DataBase.Countries
                  select new {a.Country_Id,a.Country_Name };
    CountryObject TempObject = new CountryObject();
    List<CountryObject> TempList = new List<CountryObject>();
    foreach (var a in Country)
    {
        TempObject.setCountry_Id(a.Country_Id);
        TempObject.setCountry_Name(a.Country_Name);
        TempList.Add(TempObject);
    }
    return TempList;

}
```

but when I run the code I get a List that contains the same Object, and this object have the values that get from the last round of Foreach.

I try the Following :

```
public List<CountryObject> ReturnAllCountries()
{
    ProjectTwoDataBaseDataContext DataBase = new ProjectTwoDataBaseDataContext();
    var Country = from a in DataBase.Countries
                  select new {a.Country_Id,a.Country_Name };
    CountryObject TempObject;
    List<CountryObject> TempList = new List<CountryObject>();
    foreach (var a in Country)
    {
        TempObject = new CountryObject();
        TempObject.setCountry_Id(a.Country_Id);
        TempObject.setCountry_Name(a.Country_Name);
        TempList.Add(TempObject);
    }
    return TempList;

}
```

and I get what I want >> WHy ????

Answer (score 3):

The two loops do very different things:

1. In the first example, you're only creating one object/ Then every time through the loop, modifying the same object, then re-adding it to the list. So your list contains a bunch of references to the same object, over and over again.

   This happens because `CountryObject`, like all classes is a reference type. When you add the instance to `TempList` you are only adding a reference to that instance, not a copy of it, so when you later modify the instance, those changes will be reflected in the list because it only has a reference to the same instance.
2. In the second example, creating a new object on every iteration and adding that newly created object to the loop.

   Because you're creating a new instance every time, the instances which the list references are not getting modified.

**Further Reading**

- [Value Types and Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Your first code snippet only creates one object that you put into the list multiple times.  The second creates one per iteration of the `foreach` loop.

On another note I would suggest changing `CountryObject` to have `Id` and `Name` properties and you won't need to use an anonymous class in the `Linq` query.  Properties are preferable over get and set methods.

```
public class CountryObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public List<CountryObject> ReturnAllCountries()
{
    ProjectTwoDataBaseDataContext DataBase = new ProjectTwoDataBaseDataContext();
    var Country = from a in DataBase.Countries
                  select new CountryObject{Id=a.Country_Id, Name=a.Country_Name };
    return Coutry.ToList();
}
```